# Encryption / Decryption file using metamask pub & private keys

Tags: metamask, polygon, ipfs, cryptography

*Hey Folks*, I am trying to encrypt my file before uploading it on ipfs using metamask, then I want to decrypt this file using metamask.

Can any one has idea how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

To encrypt: https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util -> [encrypt()](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util/blob/67a95bab3f414ed8a5718fcb4beccc6088c0db0e/src/encryption.ts#L22)

*Encryption won't require a Metamask interaction, only the publicKey value.*

---

To decrypt, you can use the code:

```typescript
const decrypt = await window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_decrypt',
    params: [ct, account],
});
```

---

You can check the references and explanation [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/exchanging-encrypted-data-on-blockchain-using-metamask-a2e65a9a896c).

Comment: Thank you, but I got the answer for that, same answer I found for the question.